# Is it possible to know the value of LOCAL_SRC_FILES before compiling starts?

Tags: android, makefile

I'm completely new to Android development, but I'm facing this problem. We have an Android application project. It uses `Android.mk` and there are some `ifeq...else...endif` clauses which assign different values to `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

Is it possible, with a command or a tool, to know the value of `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` before compiling starts, given that the compiling environment has been initialized?

Comment: I'm confused by the terminology. What do you mean by "know"? How would you use this knowledge?

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your comment. After the compiling starts, we can use `$(warning $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))` to print its value, right? Is there any method to get its value without compiling? The situation is that we have lots of apks in the repository. I want to know which apk will be used as `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, kind of. You could add a rule that prints LOCAL_SRC_FILES and run make on that, e.g. `make print_local_src_files` with this in makefile:

```
print_local_src_files:
    @echo $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)
```

If you can't or won't edit `Android.mk`, you can source multiple makefiles in a single make invocation:

`make -f Android.mk -f print.mk print_local_src_files`